# WOULD in clauses after WISH

Tags: grammar, clauses

I want to ask if this sentence is correct, especially the part about **would** in the clause after **wish**

> I don't wish life would be easy for me, but rather it teaches me as
>   many lessons as it can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a native speaker. Take it into account.

I wish - means that you want something to be the other way around, because in reality it is not the way you want it to be. "I wish I were you" - I will *never* be you but I wish I were.

So, when you say "I don't wish life would be..." you are sure that life will be easy for you in the future. I don't think that you really want to imply that. "would" refers to the future, by the way, in your sentence. I also don't think that "would be" and "rather teaches" match. They are in different tenses which is not good in my view. I would change it to

I hope life won't be easy for me but rather it will teach me as many lessons as it can.
or
I don't want my life to be easy for me but I want it to teach me as many lessons as it can.